# JSF 2.0: wrong language selected after deploying to another server

Tags: java, apache, jsf, tomcat

I made a web-application with JSF 2.0. It supports german (default) and english, which is selected by the languages, sent in the http-header.

On my local server (Tomcat 6.0) the automatic language-selection was correct, if I had "german" on  the highest priority, the application was german. The same for english.

But now I deployed it to my webserver (Tomcat 6.0 behind an Apache Webserver, using ModJk) and now it is only in english. But the http header is still the same:

```
Accept-Language:      de-de,en-us;q=0.8,de;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
(Fetched from Firebug)
```

The entry for the language-packs in my faces-config.xml looks like this:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>de</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>de.citkomm.tbm.locale.Lang</base-name>
        <var>lang</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

Files "Lang.properties" and "Lang_en.properties" in de.citkomm.tbm.locale are correctly deployed.

Is this a problem with Apache + ModJk + Tomcat 6.0 or is something misconfigured? Does anyone have an idea why the wrong language is selected by Tomcat?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must debug the request headers on server side, not on client side. HTTPD or modjk may have stripped/changed it before forwarding to Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange... I would think that mod_jk should not affect this as you verify that the HTTP header still contains the correct `Accept-Language`.  For a sanity-check if you are on the same internal network then you can try accessing the Tomcat web app directly and skip the Apache Web Server altogether, however I doubt this is the problem.

If you have any common libraries deployed on your Tomcat server environment then it is possible that a different version of your JSF implementation is being used, possibly an earlier version that has an internationalization bug.

I have seen this occur on application servers like JBoss and Glassfish that by default come prepackaged with their own JSF implementation.  Likewise the JBoss/Glassfish classloaders gave preference to the bundled JSF implementation libraries versus any JSF implementations that appear in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Tomcat 6 however does not do this by default but I still suspect a classloading issue of some kind.  Double check your common libraries and deployed libraries on the web server and verify that the correct JSF implementations exist there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *don't know why* tomcat uses the evironment-variable of my Ubuntu Server, but it does.

Changed LANG from "en_US.UTF-8" to "de_DE.UTF-8" and now everything's fine. :S

Thanks anyway!